# Did I brick my laptop?

Tags: boot, 16.04, laptop

So I just installed the new Version 16.04 on my Dell Latitude e5520 (which had linux 14 on it) and I did a clean install.
After the install I closed the lid and it should have been put to sleep, however when I opened it nothing happened. When I press the power button it starts to glow and I hear the Fan and then it just abruptly shuts down without monitor output or any bios/boot on screen.
I did have some similar issue in the past but I can not remember How i fixed it, anyone an idea?
EDIT
My assumption is that the HDD is stuck on "sleep" or something like that..

Answer (score 0):

Changed power outlet and it started working.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! Feel free to "accept" your answer by clicking on the gray check mark next to it; that way people can see at a glance that your issue is resolved.

Comment: @NickWeinberg thank nick, I just need to wait 2 days, but I will make sure I check it!